# why query is successful but returning 0 rows?

Tags: php, mysql

maybe I am overlooking something painfully obvious, but here is my problem. I am selecting information from my database (which I know should return 4 results) and the select runs successfully but when I try to count the number of results I get a null.

I have the following in my php code

```
$query = "select ORDERS.order_id, PRODUCT.name, PRODUCT_ORDERS.quantity,  
PRODUCT.sell_price, ORDERS.date from ORDERS, PRODUCT, PRODUCT_ORDERS where 
ORDERS.order_id = PRODUCT_ORDERS.order_id AND PRODUCT.product_id = 
PRODUCT_ORDERS.product_id and ORDERS.customer_id = $customer_id";

$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);



if (mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    echo "Successfully run query: $query";
} else {
    echo "Invalid input error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}

 $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 echo $num; //test to see if i get a number
```

I have used the same select statement in mysql workbench and it worked and returned 4 results as expected. Is there something specific in PHP that I should be looking out for? Thanks.

Comment: problem is with executing query twice!!

Comment: @Salty, not too sure. I originally had it without the successful/fail block  and it was not working then either. Added it to try to debug but its returning "succesfully" when I was expecting it to fail. Weird

Comment: You're passing a variable called `$result` (singular) into `mysqli_num_rows`, but earlier you stored the result of the query in a variable called `$results` (plural). Is that a typo in your question, or your actual code?

Comment: @paulpro yes I also noticed it

Comment: Also try echo $query to see the generated query and try it in mysql workbench

Comment: wow can't believe I missed that. thanks. yep returning four results as expected. great!

Comment: By the way, if I do `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)` do I need to give my column results aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$num = mysqli_num_rows($results);
echo $num;
```